# Someone else's answer was preloaded in my window

Tags: bug, migrated-questions, draft

So I clicked on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478851/what-is-in-php-ini

The question was [migrated to Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/407671/39535). When I clicked on it, an answer was preloaded as a draft in my window. I have never been on Server Fault before, so I was not logged in and had no account. Presumably I got attached to someone else's account.

Comment: Did you post it anyways? :P

Comment: @MichaelMrozek And yet it happened anyway. I did not write that text.

Comment: @MatthewRead I did :) I have no idea who wrote it, but it was accurate to the question.

Comment: @Michael: I didn't think they were? I thought they were sent with the heartbeat every ~45 seconds and stored on there?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Actually, I'm quite sure they are stored on the server

Comment: @michaelm they are stored on the server, I use multiple devices and they sync (though IIRC the mobile version only fetche the draft, and doesn't save it)

Comment: Drafts are indeed saved on the server, not locally (/cc @MichaelMrozek). For not-logged-in users, the draft key is attached as a cookie. Did you use a computer that had previously been used by someone else?

Comment: Smart implementation, @balpha! I see that the cookie is just valid for a day (and the expiration is not extended upon each save of a draft, isn't that odd?), so this should have been another user within the last 24 hours, Ariel.

Comment: Actually, @Ariel, if you know how to peek into the cookies, then you might still be able to find that cookie and then see when it was received. Then you know exactly when someone else was using that computer!

Comment: @balpha It's impossible that anyone else had used this computer before. I know how to look at cookies, although it's been more than 24 hours, but also, I've logged in since then, so I assume any cookie has been overwritten. (Or maybe not, if I remember correctly, when I logged in it didn't loose the draft.)

Comment: @Arjan Is there a particular cookie I should look for and write down and/or post? I also have a backup from about 17 hours ago.

Comment: Possibly draft keys are not unique, or based on a low-resolution timestamp?  Pure speculation here...